# Как снять ограничение на использование сертификатов sha1 в windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, sha1

Добрый день!

Как снять ограничение на использование сертификатов sha1 в windows 10?

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, зачем?

Comment: Старое приложение клиент/сервер использует его, а обновить это приложение нет возможности.